# How do I load static JavaScript files inside django framework

Tags: javascript, django, django-staticfiles

I know I'm doing something wrong, after consulting the docs and watching 3 YouTube videos that get it spun up in the first 7 min and copying them it still doesn't work

I'm basically trying to get to hello world from clicking a button

The Relevant lines in my HTML

```
{% extends 'box2.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
     <button class="btn btn-success mt-3" type="button" onclick="handle_do_thing_click()" type="">Add Planner</button>
{% endblock %}
{% block js_block %}
    <script type = "text/javascript/" src="{% static 'js/doThing.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

my settings.py static settings

```
INSTALLED_APPS = ['django.contrib.staticfiles']

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / 'static']
```

my url.py file

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [ these work
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

and my js file which exists in app/static/js/doThing.js is hello world

```
function handle_do_thing_click() {
    console.log("hello world");
}
```

The console error is
Uncaught ReferenceError:
handle_do_thing_click is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Answer (score 0):

For me, removing `type="text/javascript/"` from `<script>` tag make it work.

Comment: That didn't work put thanks for your suggestion